# rectangle detection only detecting large rectangles not smaller ones? iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rectangles, detect

I am using vision to detect rectangles but it only seems to be detecting larger rectangles that are more square than rectangle. Is there a way to detect longer rectangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust the `minimumAspectRatio` of the `VNDetectRectanglesRequest` which is 0.5 per default. The green rectangle seems to have a much lower one.

Comment: Oh thank you for your reply on this, I will give this a look tomorrow. It makes sense.

Comment: Great, I checked this out and it works perfectly.... Thank you for this